# How to prevent AWS Glue crawler from reading wrong data types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am running AWS Glue crawler on a CSV file. This CSV file has a string column which has alpahanumeric values. The crawler is setting the data type for this columns as INT (instead of string). This is causing my ETL to fail. Is there anyway to force glue to correct this ? I don't want to put schema manually in crawler as that defeats the purpose of automatic data catalogging.

Comment: It is INT because all its values must be numbers. Why do you think the values are not numbers?

Comment: @Marcin - I am sure that its not just numbers. I downloaded the csv file manually and created a list of all unique values. It has numbers, letters and alphanumeric. However, the first couple thousand rows are indeed numbers. Is crawler just taking a sample of data to crawl on ?

Answer (score 2):

CSV is always tricky format to handle, especially if all of your columns are strings. Crawler would not be able to differentiate between headers and rows. To avoid this, you can use Glue classifier. Set the classifier with format as CSV, use `Column headings` as has headings. Add the classifier to Glue crawler.

Make sure to delete the table and re-run. Crawler will sometimes fail to pick up the modifications after running.

Comment: I think you are being slightly confused. The crawler is picking up the headers but its not detecting the correct header types (crawler is detecting column as INT instead of STRING).

Comment: ok. CSV is semi structured and these are side effects of it. Crawler takes sample when determining the data type. If probably found only numeric valuers in the sample and assumed the integer data type.

Answer (score 1):

**[Crawler Schema Detection](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-crawler-detect-schema/)**

During the first crawler run, the crawler reads either the first 1,000 records or the first megabyte of each file to infer the schema. The amount of data read depends on the file format and availability of a valid record.

---

From the [Glue developer docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html#classifier-builtin-rules):

> The header row must be sufficiently different from the data rows. To determine this, one or more of the rows must parse as other than STRING type. If all columns are of type STRING, then the first row of data is not sufficiently different from subsequent rows to be used as the header.

To bypass this, create a new CSV classifer, set **Column headings** to *Has headings* and add classifier to the crawler.

If the classifer still does not create your AWS Glue table as you want, edit the table definition, adjust any inferred types to `STRING`, set the `SchemaChangePolicy` to LOG, and set the partitions output configuration to `InheritFromTable` for future crawler runs.

Comment: The column which is being incorrectly classified as Int has actually just numerical values in first few thousand records (but it has string and alphanumeric values later on). I think that's why it's being incorrectly classified. Can I force crawler to read whole data instead of just 1000 records ? I don't want to put column headers manually as it defeats the whole purpose of schema detection.

Comment: I'm not sure about being able to change that behaviour, try setting `Column headings` to `Detect headings` for the CSV classifier and then editing the table definition as mentioned above.

Comment: "Detect headings" is the default setting. Tried multiple approaches but nothing seems to work for now.