# Glue Crawler is removing leading 0's when reading CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

For brevity sake I am just going to create a practical example:

Let's say I am ingesting a raw CSV into S3 and one of the columns is SSNO. Within the CSV format, SSNO is not wrapped in any quotes. As we all know, SSNOs can have leading 0's: 012345678. When I run my crawler, it creates a schema where SSNO is of Type bigint, and because of this it strips the leading zeroes: 12345678.

How do I either:

A) make it not strip zeroes

B) force it to read the columns as a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent AWS Glue crawler from reading wrong data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73116066/how-to-prevent-aws-glue-crawler-from-reading-wrong-data-types)

Comment: @newbie no it doesn't, that post is about making the crawler read the entirety of your data so it can detect strings of the data, not changing the data type before running the crawler